# Awesome-WM: Spawn client on same tag as parent

Tags: awesome-wm

My goal is to let clients that have a parent spawn on the same tag as their parents. Clients w/o parents should spawn on the active tag (as usual).

My first approach is to connect a signal using `client.connect_signal("manage", ...)`. However, I couldn't find a way to get the parent of a client or to check if it has a parent.
Thank you for taking a look at my problem!

---

Update 1: I found `client:get_transient_for_matching (matcher)`, but the documentation is not very helpful.

---

Update 2: Thanks to [Uli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436275/uli-schlachter) for the hint to use `client::transient_for` as an easier way to get the transient. Using

```
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)                                                          
    parent = c.transient_for               
    naughty.notify({ preset = naughty.config.presets.critical,               
                     title = "Debug",                   
                     text = tostring(c.window) .. " " .. (parent and tostring(parent.window) or "") })
                                                                                                      
    if parent then                                                                                    
        -- move new client to same tag and screen as parent                                                                          
        tag = parent.first_tag                                                                        
        screen = parent.screen                                                                        
        c:move_to_tag(tag)                                                                            
        c:move_to_screen(screen)                                                                      
    end                                                                                               
end)
```

I tried to achieve my goals and added a simple debug output using notifications. Now, only a very few new clients actually have a transient that is not `nil`. E.g., spawning `git gui` from a terminal does not have a transient. However, I strongly believe it should (or I misunderstood what a transient is).

---

Ubuntu 20LTS, Awesome WM version 4.3-4, awesome-extra 2019021001

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `c.transient_for`. This contains the client object for the "parent" window or `nil`.

Comment: Good hint. That should do the same as

```parent = c:get_transient_for_matching(function(c2)
              return true -- get first parent
          end)```